# How to get data from Google Analytics in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, google-api

I want to read my website's Google Analytics data and render in admin panel.

Here is my codes:

```
const google = require('googleapis')
const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL, null, process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, scopes)
const view_id = '196847632'

async function getData() {
    const response = await jwt.authorize()
    const result = await google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get({
      'auth': jwt,
      'ids': 'ga:' + view_id,
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'today',
      'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
    })
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL, null, process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, scopes)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'JWT' of undefined
```

How to solve this problem and get the Analtyics data to render to ejs file.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you have something issue with Proccess.env, so make sure you are getting proper values on it.

If your private key is something like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkQ\nPmG+bRj7TkHwXJf2cx99CKW3usWKgn7EqFdFHOOQ1Z01+48SxHgTCJcd5sKy8Cf1iElXOXhIyTgnRiYm5FT1p2lMv8c71G\ngwB0kSFp5fu7vB7cGJXDMKU=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

then try accessing it like:

```
const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
  process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
  null,
  process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
  scopes
);
```

Resource : [How To Use Google Analytics Reporting API With Nodejs](https://www.tutscoder.com/post/use-google-analytics-reporting-api-nodejs)